# FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=13 "An internal error occurred."

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
db.collection("places").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
    }
}
```

**Error getting documents: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=13 "An internal error occurred."**

I cannot understand what the message really means.

- I added 'GoogleService-Info.plist' file.
- I added 'FirebaseApp.configure()' in 'AppDelegate.swift' file.

I realized one thing. **It doesn't happen after the Firebase user logged on.**
Below is my data security rule. But I cannot understand why it works like that.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
    match /places/{place} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /placeComments/{placeComments} {
        allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you figured it out

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't. I don't use Firestore anymore.